# Getting exception when I try to extend ORMLite's BaseDaoImpl

Tags: android, dao, ormlite

I think I eventually found a nice ORM framework for my Android applications. **Ormlite 5.0** is easy to learn and works great. However, today I faced a problem while trying to define my own DAO class by extending BaseDaoImpl (I need to perform some tasks over children tables each time I do  something on the parent one). This is my DAO class:

```
public class MyEntityDAO extends BaseDaoImpl<MyEntity, Integer> {

    public MyEntityDAO(Class<MyEntity> dataClass) throws SQLException{
        super(dataClass);
        this.initialize();
    }

    public MyEntityDAO(ConnectionSource connectionSource, Class<MyEntity> dataClass) throws SQLException {
        super(connectionSource, dataClass);
        this.initialize();
    }

    public MyEntityDAO(ConnectionSource connectionSource, DatabaseTableConfig<MyEntity> tableConfig) throws SQLException {
        super(connectionSource, tableConfig);
        this.initialize();
    }

    @Override
    public Dao.CreateOrUpdateStatus createOrUpdate(MyEntity entity) throws SQLException {
        DBHelper.getHelper(MyApp.getContext()).getChildDAO().createOrUpdate(entity.getChild());

        return super.createOrUpdate(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(MyEntity entity) throws SQLException{
        DeleteBuilder deleteBuilder = DBHelper.getHelper(MyApp.getContext()).getChildDAO().deleteBuilder();
        deleteBuilder.where().eq(ChildTable.ID, entity.getChild().getId()).prepare();
        deleteBuilder.delete();

        return super.delete(entity);
    }
}
```

And here is the definition of MyEntity class:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "MY_ENTITY", daoClass = MyEntityDAO.class)
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {
    ....
}
```

I think I'm doing it well, but every time I try to run the application, I get the error:

```
Could not call the constructor in class class [package name].MyEntityDAO
```

Two questions about this:

1. What am I missing or doing wrong?
2. Is the use of the context in the overriden methods ok or should I take the context from any other place?

Comment: Side note: since you are in the market for object mapping libraries have you considered first: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html.  I personally preferred https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow before Room was announced.

Comment: Thank you @Dave Thomas for the advise. I didn't know about those libraries. I'll take a look to Room.

Comment: What's your full exception?  I suspect that there is a "Caused by" line with more information.

Comment: You're right @Gray. The exception was "caused by" another custom DAO class, but I wrongly focused on MyEntityDAO. Now everything's working. Thanks for your clue, and for your awesome library.